# Core Data Relationships having a header entity on entities with common attributes

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, core-data

I have 3 types of entities (Job_A, Job_B, and Job_C) and each of them has a different attribute from one another. However, I would like to create an entity (e.g. "Job") that will act like as the header table that links to the 3 types of jobs I have said, containing the common attributes of the three jobs. The header entity (Job) will be my main entity to be linked to other entities like workers, or payments, etc. And this (Job) entity will be the only entity linked to the 3 types of jobs I made, for this (Job) entity will hold / determine what type of job (A, B, C) needs to be called or whatever.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6327835/1224741

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11192497/1224741

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11385306/1224741

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1474473/1224741

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6920736/832111) answer makes me believe that "Entity Inheritance" is not the right choice for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for ***Entity Inheritance***. For more on the subject, check out the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html).

Comment: You're most welcome Axel, glad to be of help! :) Also, if you're planning to display these entities on table views, I'd definitely recommend you check out the free Sensible TableView framework. Should save you a ton of time. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but core data binding framework is not included in the free version of STV :)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6920736/832111) answer makes me believe that "Entity Inheritance" is not the right choice for that.